# New files created through sshfs date from 1970

Tags: linux, command-line, mount, sshfs, autofs

I wish to mount a remote Linux directory to my local laptop using sshfs. I do this by using autofs. In `/etc/autofs/`, I therefore have in the `auto.ssh` file (I used the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS#Secure_user_access) to guide me for the options I should use):

```
cluster -fstype=fuse,rw,allow_other,IdentityFile=/home/mia/.ssh/id_rsa :sshfs\#mia@host\:
```

In the `auto.master` file I added the line:

```
/home/mia/remote        /etc/autofs/auto.ssh    uid=1000,gid=1000,--ghost,--timeout=60
```

The folder is successfully mounted and its date is accurate:

```
 drwxr-xr-x  4 root  root     0 Jan  5 19:51 remote
```

However, if I create a new file inside the remote folder, the file's date is epoch (01-01-1970).

```
$ cd remote/cluster
$ touch test
$ ls -l test
-rw-r--r-- 1 mia mia    0 Jan  1  1970 test
```

I have searched the man pages of mount, mount.fuse, sshfs, autofs but to no avail. I haven't been either able to determine if this was a bug or a feature. Is there any way to have the current date on newly created files?

In addition, I would like to know how to make the parent directory (`remote`) own by me (mia).

Comment: Is it the client a raspberry without Internet connection?

Comment: Known bug ?  https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/issues/44

Comment: No, both are up are to date Linux Manjaro distributions.

@steve From what I have seen, no this isn't the same. In this issue the date gets set as 0xffffff. My issue is that the date is actually epoch (0 or -1, I'm not quite sure)

Comment: The github link suggests it's an acknowledged bug and not fixed yet.  Further, 0xffffff *is* -1, per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement